# Do embarked medics still grant a healing bonus?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civilization V, units with the medic promotion make adjacent units heal faster.  But what if the medic is embarked?  Will units that are "on the beach" next to it still heal faster?  What about adjacent naval units?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that naval units won't heal. That requires an Admiral.

Answer (score 1):

According to the wiki, the Medic promotion can not be applied to Naval units. Although, embarked land units are not considered naval units and their medic promotion should still be active. Just by logic given by info from the wiki I am guessing that it should still work.

> *Medic:* "This unit and **all others** in adjacent tiles heal 5 additional HP per turn."

I am unable to test this as I am away from home right now. :(